# Some sort of descent theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective curve defined over a finite field $k$. We denote by $\overline{X}$ it's extension to the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$. All the questions are about coherent sheaves.

Under what conditions can we say that a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $\overline{X}$ comes, by tensorization, from a sheaf on $X$?

Is it true that if $\mathcal{F}$ on $\overline{X}$ is stable under the Frobenius morphism then it comes from a sheaf on $X$?

What about the extensions of two sheaves on $X$? Namely, let $\mathcal{F,G}$ be two sheaves on $X$. Is it true that the (sheaf)extensions of these two sheaves on $X$ are the extensions of $\mathcal{F}\otimes\overline{k}$ and $\mathcal{G}\otimes\overline{k}$ that are stable under the Frobenius?

What if, for two sheaves $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ on $X$ we have an extension $\mathcal{E}\otimes\overline{k}$ of $\mathcal{F}\otimes\overline{k}$ and $\mathcal{G}\otimes\overline{k}$, is it true that $\mathcal{E}$ is an extension of $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$?

The two last questions look to me like some sort of descent for morphisms at the derived categories level.

Edit: I forgot to specify that "sheaf"="coherent sheaf" in this topic.

Comment: By 'stable', do you mean that the Frobenius acts as the identity on $\mathcal{F}$? Surely the only such sheaf on $\overline{X}$ with this property is the sheaf which is constantly equal to $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: (ah, or direct sums of copies of this constant sheaf! Or maybe there are more interesting examples which I am missing.)

Comment: I was thinking more like the Frobenius applied to the sheaf is isomorphic to the sheaf of depart. So for example, if you tensorise a sheaf with $\overline{k}$ then the Frobenius acts on the second component and it is an isomorphism so you get the invariance... am I saying something stupid? Maybe this is not called Frobenius...

I'm thinking more in terms of equations and relations and Frobenius acting on the coefficients (you can express any sheaf as a finitely generated graded module).

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by a (nontrivial) sheaf that is *stable* under the Frobenius (explicit equations and an action on a graded module are fine with me). 

Comment: For example take $O(x)\times \overline{k}$ where $x$ is a point of order 1 on X. This is stable under Frobenius.

If you take $y$ a point of order 2 on $X$ then in $X'$ it splits in two points, say $y',y''$. Now the sheaf $O(y')$ is not stable under Frobenius. It's orbit is $\{O(y'),O(y'')\}$.

The Frobenius I'm thinking about is defined as this:

$F:X\times \overline{k}\to X\times \overline{k}$  which is identity on $X$ and $t\mapsto t^q$ on $\overline{k}$. And now $F$ acts on sheaves by pulling them back.



Comment: Need "continuity" condition on Frobenius descent datum.  For coherent sheaves, amounts to finite-order condition after descent to finite intermediate field.  For etale sheaves (of sets, abelian groups, etc.), amounts to distinction between "Weil sheaves" (in the sense of Deligne's Weil II) and usual etale sheaves. The answer to your 2nd question on extensions is surely "no", and for the 1st question on extensions you should formulate it in terms of a comparison of Ext^1, sheaf-Ext^1, and cohomologies thereof (depending on what flavor of sheaves you have in mind, which you don't make precise).

Comment: @BCnrd Sorry for not being precise. Everything in this questions is about coherent sheaves.

Could you please tell me why is the answer "no" to the second question about extensions?

Comment: Dragos, in the revised form the assertion on Ext^1 in the first Ext equation is correct: it amounts to formation of Ext-module being compatible with scalar extension of the ground field. (I assume "stable by Frobenius" means that the Ext-class is Galois-invariant.)  As for the 2nd Ext question, the answer is already false if $\mathcal{G} = 0$:  non-isomorphic coherent sheaves on $X$ can certainly become isomorphic after pullback to $X_{\overline{k}}$. 

Comment: BCnrd, regarding your last assertion: can you provide an example of two sheaves on $X$ that are not isomorphic but that become isomorphic after pulling them back to $X'$ ? 

Comment: Dragos, when I said there are examples I was thinking of "generic" $k$ and not quirks for finite $k$.  I assume you agree the initial Ext question is just a matter of idle curiosity, like "weird examples" one can have fun wasting time with when learning elementary topology.  By Lang's theorem, vector bundles on $X$ which are isomorphic on $X_ {\overline{k}}$ are isomorphic. The torsion analogue is clear. I tried for a bit, and I'm now not sure if a finite field quirk rules out all counterexamples. The whole premise seems unnatural, so I'll let you ponder it yourself. Have fun. :)

Comment: BCnrd, acually it was not a matter of idle curiosity because I wanted to compute extensions between some sheaves and it turned out that it was much easier to compute them over the algebraic closure. Then I would have liked to be able to descend the result to the finite field - hence the question I posted.